# Django crazy URL rewrites

Tags: python, django, templates, url

I'm currently facing an issue that I really don't understand at all, I searched through the whole code and was not able to find any references there, I deleted all caches, databases, venv etc. With no effects at all.

It's all about the 'login' url pattern

urls.py

```
from Project_Accounts import views as Project_Accounts
....
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    # Reg and Auth
    url(r'^login/$', Project_Accounts.login, name='login'),
    url(r'^signup/$', Project_Accounts.signup, name='signup'),
....

urlpatterns += [
    path('Project_Accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
]
```

base.html

```
{% if user.is_anonymous %}
    <a href="{% url 'signup' %}" class="top-menu">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Sign-Up</button>
    </a>
    <a href="{% url 'login' %}" class="top-menu">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
    </a>
{% endif %}
```

views.py (Project_Accounts)

```
def login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = LoginForm(request.POST, request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = request.POST['username']
            password = request.POST['password']
            user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
            if user is not None:
                request.session.flush()
                if user.pubpgp:
                    if user.pubpgp_enabled:
                        request.session['userID'] = user.pk
                        return redirect(reverse('login_2fa'))
                    else:
                        hybridlogin(request, user)
                        return redirect(reverse('home'))
                else:
                    hybridlogin(request, user)
                    # Redirect to a success page.
                    return redirect(reverse('home'))
        else:
            return render(request, 'Project_Accounts/login.html', {'form': form})
    else:
        return render(request, 'Project_Accounts/login.html', {'form': LoginForm()})
```

If my base.html gets displayed, signup view works fine, and every other also except the login. The URL I get back for login is

```
127.0.0.1:8000/Project_Accounts/login
```

but it used to be

```
127.0.0.1:8000/login
```

Any idea why that can appear?!

There is really no reference here and the error that gets generated by the WSGI server is:

```
TemplateDoesNotExist at /Project_Accounts/login/
registration/login.html
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/Project_Accounts/login/
Django Version: 2.1.4
Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist
Exception Value:    
registration/login.html
```

Where does registration/login.html comes from!?!?

Makes no sense to me and I also don't find any reference here in my code.

I'm thankful for every hint.

Kind regards.

Comment: Why have you included the auth URLs as well as your own login URL? That's your problem.

Comment: @Daniel Roseman: Thx for this hint, i first tought i had to use it in order to get my own auth model working, thank you very very much sir :D